# Good book on system identification for non-linear systems?

Tags: control, linear, model, non-linear

Can anyone suggest a good book that describes how to experimentally identify and describe non-linear behavior in real world systems? I have had good success analyzing systems using linear methods such as fitting transfer functions to real data. However I find that I want to expand my knowledge of how to properly describe non-linear aspects of an unknown system for which a perfect transfer function may not exist.

I want to know what tests to do. How to process frequency response chirp data. How to form the chirp to cover largest solution space (ie for a non-linear system the input to output describing function may depend on amplitude of the input signal. How to identify this and capture it in mathematical form??).

So what are some good books on this subject that dive into it in depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical book on the matter is *Lennart Ljung, "System Identification: Theory for the User"*.

In reality this is an active area of research and you may be better off looking at journals, but it depends on what you want from your models.

As you may be aware you can model things on a scale between **white-box** (models derived from physics) to **black-box** (models that are based solely on observations of a system).

Looking at chirps you may be interested in black-box and the swept-sine technique. Here are some papers that cover interesting parts:

*Simultaneous measurement of impulse response and distortion with a swept-sine technique*, Angelo Farina

*Further investigations in the emulation of nonlinear systems with volterra series*, Lamberto Tronchin and Vanna Lisa Coli

These identify nonlinear audio devices that are modelled using Volterra series and similar black-box models.

Comment: Thank you! Here I'm mostly interested in literature for identifying unknown models. I use both white box and black box models currently but I want to find better ways to identify and model the aspects of the system for which a precise white box model may not be known. Also, a lot of times when I use matlab to produce a model fit, it is typically just a transfer function which is not parametric in any way so identifying what quantities each number represents becomes problematic. So I want to gain a deeper knowledge of the underlying methods so I don't have to rely on matlab for doing this.

Comment: So what you’re talking about is finding underlying physical models, which is incredibly system dependent and would require further specification.